# Eclipse for PHP Developers needs JRE

Tags: php, eclipse, java

I have downloaded Eclipse for php development.
After execution it asks me to install the java runtime environment,
but why would I need it, if i want to develop php?
So is it the usual case that eclipse distribution for php needs the jre as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need it because Eclipse IDE is written in Java, hence, to run it, you need a Java Runtime Environment.

You won't be using Java directly to compile or develop PHP scripts though...

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is a Java application written in Java.  You will need the Java Runtime Environment to be able to run it, even if you're not writing Java yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse itself is written in Java so you need a JRE to run Eclipse even if you're not using it for Java development